# error when displaying the database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a button called find geopoint. on clicking that button I am supposed to go to another activity. In that activity I have displayed the database in a listview but when I click that button the app crashes. Here's my code:

```
public Display (String lat,String lon,String address ,String name1)
{
   this.lat=lat;
   this.lon=lon;
   this.address=address;
   Geo_Create_Table=name1;
}

public void display()
{
    Log.d("hussain", lat);
    db=d.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.query(Geo_Create_Table, new String[]{lat+"",lon+"",address}, null,null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) 
        {
        c.moveToFirst(); // it's very important to do this action otherwise your Cursor object did not get work
            int lat = c.getColumnIndex("latitude"); 
            int lon = c.getColumnIndex("longitude"); 
            int add = c.getColumnIndex("address"); 
            if (c.isFirst()) 
            { 
                int i = 0; 
                /* Loop through all Results */ 
                do 
                { 
                     i++; 
                     String latitude1 = c.getString(lat); 
                     String longitude1 = c.getString(lon);
                     String add1 = c.getString(add); 

                     /* Add current Entry to results. */ 
                     results.add("" + i + ": " + latitude1 + " (" + longitude1 + ": " + add1 + ")"); 
                } while (c.moveToNext()); 
           }
        }       
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results)); 
  }
```

pls help i have shared the db between 2 activities it is called geo_create_table

Comment: What is `d`? Is it initialised? And could you please post LogCat output so we can see what the error you're getting is. I suspect it may be a `NullPointerException` at `d.getReadableDatabase()`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Please post the logcat log as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the LogCat output (please do post it so we can pinpoint the issue), I can only guess that one of `d` or `results` is uninitialised, causing a `NullPointerException`. Neither of these are initialised in the constructor you posted, so this seems likely. It could also be that `results` is not set up to take objects of type `String`, but I doubt that's it.